# Iterate over line of string nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a massive text file that looks like :

```
e10_04txyscelsxeu4j63dx49b7nh3dzsn_q33_fdgskfdn_q53
e2_05txyscelsxeu4j63dx49b7nh3dzsn_q11_fdgskfdn_q13
e9_01_1txyscelsxeu4j63dx49b7nh3dzsn_q06_fdgskfdn_q42
e10_23txyscelsxeu4j63dx49b7nh3dzsn_q04_fdgskfdn_q41
```

There's a list of these random strings. I'm trying to iterate over each of the lines, grab the first `10` letters/numbers and spit them out somewhere so I can do something with them.

At the moment i'm iterating over every letter like so :

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('myData', 'utf8', (err, data) => {

    for (var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (i == 10) {
            console.log('test');
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Is there anyway I can do what i'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could read the file one line at a time using`readline`:

```
// this creates a read stream 

var reader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

// then here you would be able to manipulate each line:

reader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('The current line is: ', line);
});
```

Comment: Ahh cheers man. I didn't know you could `readline` I thought i'd had to read the file then pull it out lines or something that would be painful

Answer (score 1):

You should use readline module as @jordanhendrix said.

To grapes first 10 characters for each line, you can use

line.substring(0, 10);